# javascript increments misunderstanding

Tags: javascript

```
  </!DOCTYPE html>
</html>
</body>

<p>Given that y=5, calculate x=++y, and display the result.</p>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction()
{
var y=5;
var x=++y;
var demoP=document.getElementById("demo")
demoP.innerHTML="x=" + x + ", y=" + y;
}
</script>

<p><strong>Note:</strong> Both variables, x and y, are affected.</p>
</body>
</html>*/
```

Clearly, I'm a beginner but I have no one else to ask. It would be helpful if someone could explain the reason behind `demop.innerHTML="x=" + x + ", y=" +y;` in this code.

Comment: the reason is on the <p> tag.

Comment: Not the answer, but `</!DOCTYPE html>`, and your opening `html` and `body` tags should not have a forward slash. There is an extraneous `*/` at the end of the document as well?

Comment: the answer is i neglected to look over what is there. the poor writing came into me putting it up bad but had nothing to do with my problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> it would be helpful if someone could explain the reason behind demop.innerHTML="x=" + x + ", y=" +y; in this code

That line of code doesn't increment anything, in that line the `+` is a string concatenation operator, not a number addition operator. It's used for building up a string (it doesn't change `x` or `y`), which is then assigned to `demoP.innerHTML`, which replaces the content of the DOM element with that string's contents.

The line that's a bit harder to understand for a beginner is this one:

```
var x=++y;
```

That does three things:

1. It declares a variable called `x` in the current scope (`var`).
2. It increments the value of `y`.
3. It assigns the *incremented* value to `x`.

So both `x` and `y` end up with `6`, since the increment happens *before* the value of `y` is used to initialize `x`. This is called a "prefix increment". "Pre" because it happens before we use the value for something.

Like most languages that derive their main syntax from B (so, C, C++, Java, C#, JavaScript, and many others), there's also a "postfix" increment:

```
var x = y++;
```

"Post" because we increment *after* using the value. If the line were as above, `x` would get `5` (`y`'s old value) and `y` would get `6`.

Comment: @JordanBeidatsch: No worries! Part of being a beginner. Glad this helped, anyway.

Answer (score 1):

```
demoP.innerHTML = "x = " + x + ", y = " + y;
```

This sets the HTML of the element identified by `demoP`. `+` will concatenate the strings and the numbers into one string which will be the HTML of `demoP`.

Answer (score 0):

When you click the button "Try it" the function `myFunction()` is executed and the HTML inside the element with id `demo` is changed to: x=6, y=6